# Django nested relation data

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I'm using Django and Django-rest-framework, and I have the next Model and Serializer:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    id_category = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1, editable=False)
    name = models.TextField(null=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id_category', 'name', 'parent')
```

Now, I want to make a query like `Category.objects.filter(parent=None)` that returns something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id_category": "UUID",
    "name": "Father",
    "childrens": [
      {
        "id_category": "UUID",
        "name": "Son",
        "childrens": [
          {
            "id_category": "UUID",
            "name": "Grandson"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id_category": "UUID",
    "name": "Other"
  }
]
```

As you see, a Category could have one father and many children. Need help to make this query, because I don't know how do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can write additional serializer for child category:

```
class ChildrenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
         model = Category
         fields = ('id_category', 'name', 'parent')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildrenSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id_category', 'name', 'parent', 'children')
```

You [could also show nested models with depth option](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization):

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id_category', 'name', 'parent', 'children')
```